# Error when someone tries to repeat an action in rails app -- how to handle?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have rails 4 and am running postgresql for an event registration app. Users are registered through devise.

If a user has already clicked "join" to register for an event and tries to do it again, they get a generic 404 error.

I want to do something like `<%= if user_signed_in? %>` in order to hide the "Join" link if someone has already joined an event. Is that possible? I would like this on both the `index.html.erb` and `show.html.erb` for the index of events as well as the `show` page for each individual event.

Alternatively, is it possible to create some Javascript that tells the user "Hey, you already signed up for this so you can't do it again"?

This is the current code in `index.html.erb`:

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <div class="event">
    <strong> <%= event.event_name %>  </strong>
    <p><%= event.location %> <br>
    <%= event.event_date_time.strftime("%A %D at %I:%M %p") %></p>
    <div class="meta">
        <% link_name = "Join" %>
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <%= link_to "Join", join_path(event) %> |
            <%= link_to "Show", event_path(event) %>
          <% end %>
          <% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
          <span class="admin"> | <%= link_to "Edit", edit_event_path(event) %> |
        <% message = "Are you sure you want to delete this event?" %>
        <%= link_to "Delete", event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: message} %>
        <% end %>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Github repo: https://www.github.com/yamilethmedina/wheels_registration

Test server: http://wheels-registration-yamilethmedina.c9.io (it's also deployed on Heroku if that makes a difference in your answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little impractical to use devise, an authentication system as an event registration system. It may be more suitable to have users create an account through devise then collect additional data and store it as an attendee model etc. Either way you should be able to get the desired behavior.

```
<% unless user_signed_in? %> 
  <%= link_to "Join", join_path(event) %> 
<% else %> 
  <%= link_to "Show", event_path(event) %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: that's actually what i'm doing. users are registering through devise and the event registration is a separate model. I already have what you propose working -- the Join link only shows if a user is signed in. what I want is for the join link to NOT show up (or give a descriptive error) if the user has PREVIOUSLY JOINED that SAME event. right now, it lets them do it and throws a generic 404 that explains nothing.

Comment: Ah, you will have to place a cookie or maintain a session to identify them unless they are logged in again. Not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: that makes sense. i'm pretty sure devise already leaves cookies; I just want to make sure that those cookies include all of this data, which i'm not sure is possible

Answer (score -1):

Let's imagine that there is a form with submit button. So script will be looked like:

`$('#myForm').one('submit', function() {
    $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
});`

Comment: this is the current code (will edit question):  `<% link_name = "Join" %>
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <%= link_to "Join", join_path(event) %> |
            <%= link_to "Show", event_path(event) %>
          <% end %>` Where would your javascript go?

Comment: the meaning is not changed. the point is to disable the link. and you should to work with result html instead of erb to locate dom object with javascript